# Correct order of various phases of MR job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am trying to understand the various phases which a MR Job goes through. I read online documentation for the same.

Based on this, my understand on the sequence is as below:

map() -> Partitioner -> Sorting (at mapper machine) -> Shuffle -> Sorting (at reducer machine) -> groupBy(Key) (at reducer machine) -> reduce()

Is this the correct sequence in which a MR Job executes?

Answer (score 2):

Various phases of a map reduce job:

Map phase:

- Reads assigned input split from HDFS
- Parses input into records as key-value pairs
- Applies map function to each record
- Informs master node of its completion

Partition phase

- Each mapper must determine which reducer will receive each of the outputs
- For any key, destination partition is the same
- No. of partitions = No. of reducers

Shuffle phase

- Fetches input data from all map tasks for the portion corresponding to the reduce task's bucket

Sort phase

- Merge sorts all map outputs into a single run

Reduce phase

- Apply user defined reduce function to merged un
- Argument are the key and corresponding list of values
- Writes output to a file in HDFS

Answer (score 1):

**Timeline of Map Reduce Job**

[image]

- Map Phase: several Map Tasks are executed
- Reduce Phase: several Reduce Tasks are executed

**Timeline for MapTask**

[image]

**Timeline for ReduceTask**

[image]

Image source : https://www.slideshare.net/EmilioCoppa/hadoop-internals

Comment: But what about other important phases? Sorting, partitioning, group by (key) ?

Comment: `Sorting` is part of `spilling` and `group by` takes place just before shuffling (can say part of spill management). partitioning is not a phase, rather it is a way to choose the right `reducer`. Indeed there is an optional phase of `Combining`, if Combiner class is given to the job.