# Understanding the different elements of Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm teaching myself Hadoop and the Map Reduce programming model. I'm trying to understand **it's core elements:** I'm trying to match each of the elements below to the features below:

- Reducer
- Combiner
- Shuffle and Sort
- Mapper
- Partitioner
- Replication

The features I have to map the above Hadoop components are:

-**Grouping, move computation to data, help with copy-phase bottleneck, load, balancing, data filtering, global computation**

My understanding:
Reducer--->global computation, Combiner---> grouping, shuffle and sort(process of moving data from the mappers to the reducers)-->move computation to data. Mapper-->(data filtering)
Partitioner-->load balancing, and lastly replication-->helps with copy-phase bottleneck.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could check my understanding of the basic hadoop components and correct me where necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct order of various phases of MR job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187138/correct-order-of-various-phases-of-mr-job)

Comment: Replication isn't part of MapReduce, only the HDFS protocol

Answer (score 0):

Replication → Move computation to data, Combiner → Helps with copy phase bottleneck, Mapper → Data filtering, Reducer → Global computation, Partitioner → Load balancing, Shuffle and Sort → Grouping